# Code about waveform creation ...help--

Tags: java

Does anybody could explain to me , the meaning of these code statements?

```
1)    List<Byte> audioBytes;
    List<Line2D.Double> lines;
```

what's Line2D.Double? What these "< ..>" stand for?

Also:

```
2) public void resetWaveform() {
                audioBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
                lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Double>();
                repaint();
            }
```

and :

```
3) public void addAudioByte(byte b) {
                audioBytes.add(b);
            }

            public void createWaveForm() {

                if (audioBytes.size() == 0) {
                    return;
                }
```

Thanks for your help.
Carlos .

Comment: Thanks , I'm a beginner and I do need to understand that code. So I'd like someone to help me..thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Line2D.Double](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.Double.html)
The < and > syntax is for [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) support.  audioBytes is a List of Byte and lines is a List of Line2D.Double.

resetWaveform is resetting the data structures and addAudioByte adds the next byte of the audio stream to the collection.

Comment: So this is a data structure?
audioBytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
lines = new ArrayList<Line2D.Double>();
Can I say that they are actually containers for audio samples and line coordinates related to the audio samples?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to write Java? Take a look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/index.html first